# ObjectOutputStream hanging forever

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a client that connects to a server using SSLSocket.  Next, I try to create an OOS with `ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());`

If everything is working well on the server side, this is fine.  However, I would like to put something in place on my client side that tries to create the ObjectOutputStream, but if it hasn't happened in 60 seconds, log the error and continue processing.  I don't see any timeout options for this.  Any examples of how this could be done?

```
     SSLSocket sslsocket;
     try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", <myKeystore>);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", <myPW>);
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), <myPort>);

     } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.logError(e.getMessage());
            return null;
     }

      // This is where it hangs forever
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
      oos.flush(); // never gets here
      oos.writeObject(orders);

      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the ObjectOutputStream before the ObjectInputStream.

**EDIT:** See comments below. The real problem was a slow SSL handshake, which happens in the first I/O on the socket, and during which reads are performed as well as writes. So the solution was to set a read timeout.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You don't have to flush, it happens internally. There's no reason why he needs a timeout at all, it will happen immediately.

Comment: @EJP, what do you mean?  I'm seeing that that the creation of the oos is hanging forever when the server is unresponsive

Comment: My problem is that the connection hangs forever.  In the larger scheme of my project, I want to include some kind of timeout if there is an issue on the server side which is outside of my control

Comment: @Marianna I suspect what you are seeing is the creation of the ObjectInputStream hanging. There's no reason for the output stream to hang, it all goes into the socket send buffer, no waiting.

Comment: I added the code and some comments as to where I am getting.  I put in print statements so I could tell which lines it was hitting

Comment: @Marianna OK so what you need is a *read* timeout on the socket, to catch SSL handshake problems.

Comment: Ah ha!  I was being tricked by the fact that it was able to get to the line of code where it created the OOS, but in reality, it was hanging there because the handshake was incomplete.  Your suggestion worked well, I just added `sslsocket.setSoTimeout(60000);` at the end of my try block.  Thank you!